# AES/GCM encryption on Android (Java), 'or' Kotlin statement equivalent in Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, encryption, aes-gcm

I'm trying to implement encryption in my app. I found some Kotlin code on GitHub and tutorials on how to implement it, until I found this block:

```
val kgps = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("my_aes_key", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
        // This is required to be able to provide the IV ourselves
        .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
        .build()
```

I'm still using Java for the Android app, I'm still wondering how can I implement this line in Java (or what is the equivalent statement for it)?

```
KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
```

I'm facing a compile error if I try to replace the `or` with `||` binary operator, since that operator isn't compatible with for comparing integers. The error seems missing when I use the bitwise `|` operator but I can't be sure, is it the correct implementation of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `or` in Kotlin is the same as `|` in Java.

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProperties#PURPOSE_ENCRYPT), `KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT` and `KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT` are both integers. That means the `or` function being used is [this one](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/or.html), which performs a bitwise or. You're correct that that's equivalent to the Java `|` operator. Kotlin doesn't have bitwise operators in the language, so it uses the infix extension functions `and` and `or` instead.